# How do you extract specific values from a column in one dataframe and append them to a column in another dataframe? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have two dataframes in pandas. df1 and df2.

```py
df1 = 'column1': ['a','b','c','a','c'], 'column2':[1,2,3,4,5]

df2 = ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC'] (empty except for these column names)
```

I want to take all the values from column1 in df1 that equal 'a' and put them into 'columnA' of df2. Then do the same for 'b' and put them in 'columnB' and then the same for 'c' and 'columnC'.

Whats the best way of doing this?

I've looked all over and can only find answers for moving entire columns, not specific values like this, so any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here to `pivot` , we need `cumcount` create the group key

```
df1['index'] = df1.groupby('column1').cumcount()
df2 = df1.pivot(index='index', columns='column1', values='column2')
```

Comment: thanks! this worked for the most part. the only question i have is values='column2'. i dont want the values from column2, i want the values from column1. column2 is not needed at all. so should it be values='column1' instead?

Comment: @user11467841 yes you can change it to column2